# How to fix this IndexError?

Tags: python, file, if-statement, while-loop, index-error

The code receives an `import_file` with elements of periodic table, written without space, e. g.

> CrCoRaLiBhMnMdSmNhPbCaUUMo...

Then the program reads elements of periodic table in Russian language into a dictionary from json file and write them to `output_file` in Russian language with no space either, thus the line

> CrCoRa...

transforms into

> ХромКобальтРадий...

and so on.

The problem is the infamous `IndexError`, which occurs in the `if (i[n] + i[n+1]) in p_t:` line. I've tried to change `while n <= len(i):` for `while n <= len(i) - 1:`, but it doesn't help.

```
import json

def periodic_table(import_file, output_file):
    p_t = json.load(open('periodic_table.json', encoding = 'utf-8'))
    with open(import_file) as i_f, open(output_file, 'w') as o_f:
        for i in i_f.readlines():
            n = 0
            while n <= len(i):
                if (i[n] + i[n+1]) in p_t: 
                    o_f.write(p_t[i[n] + i[n+1]])
                    n += 2
                elif (i[n] + i[n+1] + i[n+2]) == 'Uue':
                    o_f.write(p_t['Uue'])
                    n += 3
                elif i[n] in p_t:
                    o_f.write(p_t[i[n]])
                    n += 1

periodic_table('import_file_3.txt', 'output_file.txt')
```

Comment: You need `while n <= len(i) - 2:` as you are trying to access `i[n + 1]`. This may cause you to not detect single letter atoms at the end of the string however.

I also just saw you are trying `n + 2` as well, so you might need a check like `n + 2  < len(i)` in that elif if you want to catch that.

Comment: @Freek I have tried this too, It works, but the last element is not processed. The code bypassed it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you check i[n+1] but you don't know if it exists, so you have an IndexError, slicing a string in python will slice even if there are not the amount of characters you want to slice, so there is no IndexError.
you can try this code:

```py
    def periodic_table(import_file, output_file):
    p_t = json.load(open('periodic_table.json', encoding = 'utf-8'))
    with open(import_file) as i_f, open(output_file, 'w') as o_f:
        for i in i_f.readlines():
            while len(i) > 0:
                if len(i[0:2]) == 2 and i[0:2] in p_t:
                    o_f.write(i[0:2])
                    i = i[2:]
                elif i[0:3] == 'Uue':
                    o_f.write(p_t['Uue'])
                    i = i[3:]
                elif i[0] in p_t:
                    o_f.write(p_t[i[0]])
                    i = i[1:]
                else:
                    break # otherwise it will run forever if you have an error in the file
```

Comment: Slicing is really witty move here, thanks for it, but code doesn't work.

Comment: Yes the last condition was else not elif, I edited

Comment: I did that too, still the code doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the language translation matter, I would suggest have a discrete function that returns a list of the element symbols then go from there.

```
def getElementList(filename):
    elist = []
    with open(filename) as elements:
        for e in map(str.strip, elements.readlines()):
            i = 0
            while i < len(e):
                e1, *e2 = e[i:i+2]
                if e2 and e2[0].islower():
                    elist.append(e1+e2[0])
                    i += 1
                else:
                    elist.append(e1)
                i += 1
    return elist
```

This allows for the symbols to be split over multiple lines although a 2-character symbol which itself is split over 2 lines will not work

Comment: Thank for your suggestion, but I don't need to split elements over multiple lines, because the output should be joined in one line. The only problem is `IndexError`.

Comment: @866812 If you use my answer as the means to acquire a list of the element symbols, you won't get an IndexError. If your input file only has one line then this will still work - it's just more flexible and robust